# iOS Communicate with .Net Application

Tags: c#, ios

I am currently building an application for my iPad for a home flight simulator. The iPad will display engine data. At this point I am curious what the best way to send data from my C# application , that retrieves data from the flight simulator application, to the iPad.  I will only be sending doubles, but the information stream will be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can poll a WCF[TCP] service hosted in your local IIs which internally polls the data from the flight sim API or whatever is your data store.

Polling could consume your ipad/iphone battery fast so in that case you would need to have a duplex service and push data to your device

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the ASP.Net MVC Web API would be a candidate if this is an ASP.Net app.

However, if this is a client app (WPF, WINForm etc) I would consider a self hosted WCF service